# Concatenate using ## directive (switch cases)

Tags: macros, switch-statement, preprocessor, case, hashtag

Is there any way to generate as a preprocessor macro and the use of the concatenate directive the cases for a switch-case statement. Im using C and I would like to create several cases for a switch.case statement as.

```
#define select_case(value) \
switch (values) \ Assume an enum with the values
case prefix_##value: \
break;\
default:\
break;\
```

That is a general idea. did you get me? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Also I don't see the point of the `default` case (that wouldn't compile as there would be multiple `default`s).

Comment: can you give an example with input and expected output?